# Saved KML files will not import

Tags: google-maps, import

KML files saved from Google Maps will not work when I use "Create map" and try to import them.

I have tried from two different PCs using two different browsers (IE, Opera).

I resorted to this as a test after finding that KML files I had created were not working for import.

I am busy trying Firefox too but don't expect a result.

Is Google having a temporary problem with this?

Some other reason?

Would they block me if I have about 80 maps?

Comment: I did try Firefox -- no luck

Comment: Same here, kml files that worked yesterday cannot be imported today :(